# Python Tkinter Custom Widget (Frame) with Mousewheel Scroll Event

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, gui, tkinter

I try to write a GUI for practicing with one Window, containing two frames in a ttk.Notebook. Each of these Custom Widget Frames should have a scrollbar and the MouseWheel bound to a yscroll for the canvas which is placed in this frame.

My questions are:
- Is this a common/recommended way to do that? 
- If I do it like this the MouseWheel works only on one of the Frames of my window. Why?
- I am a beginner, so if you see any other mistakes/uncommon things, please let me know!

Here is an extraction of my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class MyFirstGUI(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.gui_control = ttk.Notebook(master)

        self.main_gui = ttk.Frame(self.gui_control, borderwidth=0) 
        self.systems_gui = ttk.Frame(self.gui_control, borderwidth=0)

        self.gui_control.add(self.main_gui, text='Main') 
        self.gui_control.add(self.systems_gui, text='Systems')

        self.gui_control.grid(column=1,row=1, columnspan=9, rowspan=50,sticky=N+E+S+W)  

        self.test_1 = Main.MainFrame(self.main_gui)
        self.test_1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NESW") 

        self.test_2 = Systems.SystemFrame(self.systems_gui)
        self.test_2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NESW") 

        #[...]

master.mainloop()
```

MainGUI:

```
class MainFrame(tk.Frame):    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)        

        self.main_canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.main_canvas.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="NESW")  

        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.main_canvas.yview)
        self.vsb.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky="NS") 

        self.main_canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)

    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.main_canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")

    #[...]
```

Systems GUI (basically the same):

```
class SystemFrame(tk.Frame):    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)        

        self.system_canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.system_canvas.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="NESW")  

        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.system_canvas.yview)
        self.vsb.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky="NS") 

        self.system_canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)

    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.system_canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")

    #[...]
```